# Img.src how is it stored in memory?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering about `image.src` and how it is stored in browsers.

Does it store an array of pixels ready to display on screen? And then that got me wondering why can we not access this pixel data `without` drawing to a canvas and getting the pixel information that way?

The image data must be stored in memory for the browser, so why can we not directly enquire a pixel of the image any other way than to draw it first?

Comment: in web terms, `img` is primordial slime compared to modern things like canvas. when img was defined in the original DOM specs, it was never intended to be anything other than a quick way to load a picture into a browser and access some metadata. as such there were no provisions to access pixels within the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard that defines how images are maintained by the browser, and because browsers are purposely designed to not let you get at their internal implementations, you really can't do what you're requesting...

Answer (score 1):

Really, how a browser stores an image in memory is irrelevant to you, the web developer.  It's an implementation detail.  It's like asking how the OS kernel decides where in RAM it allocates your program memory – for most applications, it simply doesn't matter; the kernel just gives you memory.

The only thing that matters is the publicly documented API provided to you.  In the case of the DOM APIs, the way to get pixel data is through the canvas APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Historical reasons. The image element was originally designed just to show an image. The canvas element was added many years later to give developers access to the data in images and other media objects.

At a higher level, if you're interested in the internal plumbing of how browsers *implement* their image tags, the source for Firefox and Chrome is open for inspection.